# Google Maps Javascript - addListener click event issues, Chrome vs Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, internet-explorer, firefox

I've scoured the web for an answer to this, and have tried dozens of fixes with no resolve. It's the weirdest thing. I figure it must be something I'm missing with Google maps considering I'm not super familiar with the library, I'm just updating a site someone else built. So here's a very basic version of my code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        $('#infoDiv').show().css(({ left: event.pageX, top: event.pageY }));
});
```

This works in Chrome and Safari. Now I know in Firefox and IE event isn't global, however doing this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(event) {
        $('#infoDiv').show().css(({ left: event.pageX, top: event.pageY }));
});
```

Breaks in Safari and Chrome, and doesn't work in Firefox either. I've tried using google maps to convert the lat/lng to points, I've tried defining window.event || event, I've tried defining the function outside separately, and still nothing can get it to work in Firefox or IE.

Here's the page in question: http://www.cigwireless.com/what-we-have/

Comment: It would be helpful to explain what you mean when you say it doesn't work or it breaks. Do you see an error in the console? Is the event not firing at all? Does it show the div but at the wrong position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [google.maps.Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker) [MouseEvent](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MouseEvent) which is the event object returned by the google.maps.event 'click' listener function, doesn't have pageX or pageY properties (at least that are documented).

You can convert the latLng property to an pixel position using [fromLatLngToContainerPixel(latLng:LatLng)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapCanvasProjection)